# Does the then() function return a promise reflecting the results of the previous promise?

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous, promise, async-await

I am new to promises and have studied it. So my code and my understanding:

```
sql.connect(config).then(function(connection) {
  return connection.request().query('select * from Users')
}).then(function(result) {
  console.dir(result);
  res.send(result);
}).catch((err) => {
  console.log(err);
  res.send(err)
});
}) // extra?
```

In the first line, the `connect` method returns a promise so on that, when I call a function `then` (*if connect had success*). The `then` takes callbacks i.e. "successCB", "failureCB" as arguments which actually represent the result or error returned by the `connect` promise. Correct?

Also, the "successCB" is returning the promise (from `.query`).

`then` is again called on the previous promise returned by `then`.

In case of `then` used on `connect()` why is the `then` taking a callback and how does it know of `connect`'s success since `connect` has already returned the result i.e. "successCB"?

Comment: Yes; that is correct.

Comment: `.then` does take a callback, but its generally only thought of a `success` cb. Your `.catch` would be the failure cb.

Comment: @IsaacVidrine in case of then used on connect() why the then is taking a callback and how does it know of connect's success since connect has already returned the result i.e. SuccessCB?

Comment: Maybe you meant this, but just for clarity `takes callbacks… which actually represents the result` isn't quite right. The *arguments passed* to the callback represent the result of the previous promise.

Comment: You had a lot of formatting in your post (specifically bold) that I felt made the question quite difficult to read. I've rmoed that formatting and used code formatting for those things which were code and quotation marks for others. Feel free to rollback if you disagree (click on edited .. ago).

Comment: "why is the then taking a callback ...?", because there's absolutely no point of `.then()` without a callback. Its sole purpose is to allow one or two callbacks to be specified.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for replies and I have already selected the answer. Based on the input given by you people this is what I have understood further.

```
sql.connect(config).then(function(connection) {
  return connection.request().query('select * from Users')
})
```

In the code given above, `sql.connect` part is using an `SQL` module to call a `connect()` method which is supposed to return a `promise` (in case of failure returns an error else a `connection` object). On `connect()` we call a `then()` method which takes a callback function `function(connection)` to get registered so that can be called later at the point where `connect` returns a `promise` (in case of `success` i.e. `connection` object) and later

```
.then(function(result) {
  console.dir(result);
  res.send(result);
}).
```

is called on the `promise` returned by `.query('select * from Users')` part of the previous .`then()` method's callback function and so on.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not 100% certain if you are correct, but this is how I would explain it. Lets say we have a promise *A*.

- Calling `then()` *always* returns a new promise (Lets call it *B*)
- If the callback returns a promise *C*, then promise *B* will resolve or fail with the result of promise *C*.
- If any of the callbacks returns a non-promise value *X*, then promise *B* will resolve with value *X*
- If an exception was thrown in the callback, then promise *B* will fail with the exception.
- If the main promise *A* failed, and no failure callback was given, then promise *B* will also fail with the same error.

Personally I found learning this very confusing, because it requires quite a complex mental model to fully grasp this. The day I fully understood this is the day that I wrote my own `Promise` class. I would recommend anyone who fully wants to grasp promises in every detail to take the time to do this.

Answer (score 0):

> In the first line, the `connect` method returns a promise so on that, I call a function `then` (if `connect` had success).

Almost: the `then` method is called irrespective of the `connect` promise's result. Note that the promise is most likely still pending when the `then` method is called. It is called (obviously) *synchronously*.

> The `then` takes callbacks i.e. `successCB`, `failureCB` as an args which actually represents the result or error returned by the `connect` promise. Correct?

Those callbacks are registered by the promise object, and *one* of them will be called later when the promise resolves: it can either fulfil or reject. If the promise never resolves, neither will be called. In your case, you provided just one function, the one that will be called when the promise fulfils.

> Also, the `successCB` is returning the promise (from `.query`).

True. The promise that was created when the outer `then` was executed will take over the status/value of the promise that was returned here.

> `then` is again called on the previous promise returned by `then`.

Yes, but again, it is called immediately. All chained `then`/`catch` methods are called synchronously and their job is to register the callbacks and to return a promise.

The asynchronous part is when the respective callbacks are called. This is when the cascading effect takes place. Once the first promise (`query()`) in the chain resolves, the respective callback is called and that call resolves (fulfils or rejects) the promise *that was already returned by `then`*, which triggers a next callback... etc

## Order of execution

#### Part A

1. `sql.connect(config)`

   calls `connect` and returns a promise
2. `.then(......)`

   calls `then` on the promise of A.1, registers the callback and returns a promise
3. `.catch(.....)`

   calls `catch` on the promise of A.2, registers the callback and returns a promise.
   This happens to be the last one in the chain, so this promise is the value of the whole expression.

At this point the synchronous part ends. If there is other calling code on the callstack, it gets executed, but eventually the call stack will be empty.

#### Part B

Then, some time later, there is an event indicating that the promise of A.1 is resolved, let's assume it fulfils (i.e. success). Then the first callback is executed:

1. `connection.request()` is executed

   it calls `request` which returns an object with the `query` method (among others)
2. `.query('select * from Users')` is executed

   it calls `query` with the SQL and returns a promise
3. `return` is executed

   the callback returns the promise of B.2, which becomes linked with the promise that was created in step A.1.

At this point the promise of step A.1, is still pending. Its destiny is tied up now with the promise that was returned by `query`, B.2. It that one resolves, A.1 will also resolve (with the same state & value/error).

#### Part C

Then, some time later, there is an event indicating that the promise of step A.1 is resolved, let's assume it fulfils. Then the second callback is executed:

1. `console.dir(result)` is executed
2. `res.send(result)` is executed
3. Nothing is returned, so the promise of 1.B fulfils with value `undefined`

   This fulfilment creates a next asynchronous job to execute (part D)

#### Part D

1. The promise returned by `catch` (A.3) resolves with the value with which C.3 resolved, i.e. it fulfils with value `undefined`. The callback it had registered is not executed, as it is not relevant for this scenario.

Comment: @FannyHunayn, it is easy to misunderstand each other when speaking about `then`. The `then` method is executed synchronously, the `then` *callback* is executed asynchronously.